# developing a windows service in C++ without Visual Studio template?

Tags: c++, windows-services

I have a version of Visual Studio 2005 that doesn't include a Windows Service project template.  Can I just build a (C++) console application and install it as a service without doing anything special within the application code itself.

Answer (score 1):

All the service project template does is supply you with some source code to get started. Although you can't take an ordinary console application and make it a service app, you can implement the [ServiceMain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687414(VS.85).aspx) function following the instructions on that reference page.